Getting Firebase installation failed in the release bundle file
Getting Firebase installation failed in the Android release bundle file. (React Native)
-> Exception geting in the logs.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later. at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:5) at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:9) at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(GmsRpc.java:269) at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.startRpc(GmsRpc.java:231) at com.google.firebase.messaging.GmsRpc.getToken(GmsRpc.java:181) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$blockingGetToken$14$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:650) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda8.start(Unknown Source:6) at com.google.firebase.messaging.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(RequestDeduplicator.java:67) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:646) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$7$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:421) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:4) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.3.0:2) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later. at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.createFirebaseInstallation(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:154) at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.registerFidWithServer(FirebaseInstallations.java:533) at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCallIfNecessary(FirebaseInstallations.java:387) at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationOrRefresh$3$com-google-firebase-installations-FirebaseInstallations(FirebaseInstallations.java:372) at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4) at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:117) at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:229) at com.google.firebase.concurrent.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:174) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47) at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
-> Tried with the Generate the APKS file from the release bundle file using the bundletool apks extraction and its working in the APKS file but not woking through the play store Closed and Internal testing build.
-> Tested in the real device.
-> Tried with the "Don't restrict key" and "Restrict key" in the Google cloud console for the API key.
-> Verified with the SHA-1 in the firebase project and play store "App signing" keys.
-> Used the latest the google-service.json file.
-> Already reviewed other question related to this bug but couldn't find any solution.
-> Used the updated firebase libs.
"@react-native-firebase/app": "20.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "20.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "20.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "20.4.0",
